# Changing marker symbol in Leaflet AJAX

Tags: leaflet, geojson, symbology, markers

I have got a `.json` file to display in Leaflet map.
The points are shown with custom blue dot markers. I cannot get to change them.
How do I get to change the symbol?

```
var greenIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'marker-shadow.png',
  iconSize: [38, 95] // size of the icon
}); 

var jsonTest = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(["colleges.geojson"],{onEachFeature:popUp},{icon:greenIcon});
var jsonTest1 = jsonTest.addTo(m);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`pointToLayer`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#geojson-pointtolayer) option (and mind your syntax).

```
var jsonTest = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(["colleges.geojson"],{ //options object for GeoJSON
  pointToLayer: function(geoJsonPoint, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, { icon: greenIcon }); //options object for Marker
  },
  onEachFeature:popUp
});
```

Comment: Is there any edits remaining or I shall copy paste the code?

Comment: You should try to understand what the code does.

Comment: Thank You.. It worked. just need edit in {onEachFeature:popUp}.
 Would you please up-vote question???

Comment: Glad to be able to help! Upvoting your question doesn't feel fair to me because there are questions that show noticeably more research effort than yours.

Comment: As to your proposed edit: You cannot pass two options objects to `L.GeoJSON.AJAX(...)`. Please have a look at this [example](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax/blob/1f7c87600efe3fecf782ffdff9d44c8142441204/example/local.html#L55).

Comment: Sorry, but code didn't work until i used above one...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87601/discussion-between-timilsina-aashish-and-stefan).